# Protobuff.NET - different serialization of a abstract base class

Tags: .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I would like to serialze a property of an abstract example via protobuf.net.
Could you explain what I would need to change so that this simple example works?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;
namespace TestProtobuf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new ClassB {A = "AAAA", B = "BBBB"};
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream,x);
            var memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
            var y = Serializer.Deserialize<ClassB>(memoryStream2);
            if (x.A != y.A)
                Console.Write("Failed");
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class ClassB:ClassA    
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public abstract class ClassA
    {
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string A { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add, to the base-class:

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ClassB))]
```

Basically, as with `XmlSerializer` (see: `[XmlInclude]`) and `DataContractSerializer` (see: `[KnownType]`) - the serializer needs to know about sub-classes in advance. The easiest way to do this is with attributes, but it *can* also be specified at runtime if you prefer.

Note the `1` here is just any key (preferably a small number - they encode more efficiently) that doesn't conflict with other keys in `ClassA` (so: I couldn't use `2` because `A` is `2` in `ClassA1`). Keys only need to be unique within the single class (not between different classes, even in inheritance).